# ConstraintLayout: How to set the Max Height of a child within a ConstraintLayout initial height wrap?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout called "constraintInput" inside a ConstraintLayout. "constraintInput" contains an EditText (i.e. an input field for the user). I want the user to be able to type in the EditText, and its parent "constraintInput" should grow vertically accordingly. It should not grow more than half of the screen height. At this stage, only a scrollbar should appear (inside the EditText). How do I achieve that?

This is how it looks:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQFjw.png)

This is my code so far:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
                <!-- CONSTRAINTINPUT AREA -->
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintInput"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_constraint"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideLeftWide"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideRightWide"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideTop"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" >
                    <!--TITLE-->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/titleWelcome"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        android:text="emojiCrypt"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    <!-- Radio Buttons -->
                    <RadioGroup
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleWelcome"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:id="@+id/btnRadio">
                        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioBtnT"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Text To Emoji"
                            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                            android:checked="true"/>
                        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioBtnE"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Emoji To Text"
                            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <!-- EditText Input field -->
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtTxt"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnRadio"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideLeftNarrow"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideRightNarrow"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
                        android:layout_below="@id/btnRadio"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp" />
                    <!-- Clear Button -->
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                        android:onClick="onClearClick"
                        android:text="Clear"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideLeftNarrow"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideLeftSubmit"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtTxt" />
                    <!-- Submit Button -->
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:onClick="onSubmitClick"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtTxt"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftSubmit"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideRightSubmit"/>
                    <!-- Copy Button -->
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnCopy"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCopyDrawable"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideRightSubmit"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideRightMiddleCopypasta"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtTxt"/>
                    <!-- Paste Button -->
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnPaste"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModePasteDrawable"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideRightMiddleCopypasta"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideRightNarrow"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtTxt"/>
                    <!-- INPUT CONSTRAINT LAYOUT: Guidelines for Layout -->
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guideLeftNarrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guideRightNarrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guideLeftSubmit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guideRightSubmit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guideRightMiddleCopypasta"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.775" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            
                <!-- TextView -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textarea"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintInput"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideLeftWide"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideRightWide"/>
                <!-- Main Constraint Layout Guides -->
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideLeftWide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideRightWide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideTop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideMid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
            
            
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```